# Join on smaller than date and sum the amounts (snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an opp table with the customer's purchases:

|  | CLOSED_DATE | OPP_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1/4/2022 | 6600 |
| 1 | 2/17/2022 | 9125 |

and a charges table with dates:

|  | CHARGE_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 0:00:00 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 0:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-03-15 0:00:00 |
| 3 | 2022-03-15 0:00:00 |
| 4 | 2022-04-15 0:00:00 |
| 5 | 2022-04-15 0:00:00 |

for each charge, I'd like to have the total amount of purchases on that point of time (and the amount of first purchase for dates before it):

|  | CHARGE_DATE | Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 0:00:00 | 6600 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 0:00:00 | 6600 |
| 2 | 2022-03-15 0:00:00 | 15725 |
| 3 | 2022-03-15 0:00:00 | 15725 |
| 4 | 2022-04-15 0:00:00 | 15725 |
| 5 | 2022-04-15 0:00:00 | 15725 |

tried join on charge_date<=closed_date but this brings the numbers multiple time,
any ideas?

Comment: What is 'point of time' in "Total amount of purchases on that point of time"? If its charge_date then there is nothing before 2022-01-03.

Comment: you are right, as mentioned, for charge dates prior to first closed_date I'd like to put the first amount, but if you have a solution where this stays null that's ok too, as I can fill it with a separate window function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be as follows -

```
select distinct c.id,charge_date, sum(amount) over (partition by c.id order by c.id) 
as target from charge_date c left outer
join closed_date d on closed_date<=charge_date order by c.id;


+----+-------------------------+--------+
| ID | CHARGE_DATE             | TARGET |
|----+-------------------------+--------|
|  0 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000 |   NULL |
|  1 | 2022-01-04 00:00:00.000 |   6600 |
|  2 | 2022-03-15 00:00:00.000 |  15725 |
|  3 | 2022-03-15 00:00:00.000 |  15725 |
|  4 | 2022-04-15 00:00:00.000 |  15725 |
|  5 | 2022-04-15 00:00:00.000 |  15725 |
+----+-------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: cool, thanks!!!!, a little hard to test since the number ids where not a real part of my table, my bad, I'll add and test